# Dash x-axis on top of the graph?

Tags: python

Is it possible to place date on x-axis on the top of the graph ? I'm currently using a go.Scatter on dash to do this

[image]

To have something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `update_layout` to update the figure layout

```py
fig = go.Scatter()

fig.update_layout(xaxis={'side': 'top'})
```